# Rounding numbers in complex conditions in Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I need to round up/down the numbers (last 2 digits, no decimal) based on three conditions:

1. if 00, then -1
2. if 01 to 49, then round up to 50
3. if 51 to 98, then round up to 99

examples:

- if the number is 1251, then it's 1299
- if the number is 1298, then it's 1299
- if the number is 4874, then it's 4899
- if the number is 1433, then it's 1450
- if the number is 1880, then it's 1899
- if the number is 1301, then it's 1350
- if the number is 1200, then it's 1299
- if the number is 1250, then it's 1250 (unchanged)
- if the number is 1299, then it's 1299 (unchanged)

..................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assume value is in a1

```
=IF(MOD(A1,100)=0,A1-1,IF(MOD(A1,100)<51,A1+50-MOD(A1,100),A1+99-MOD(A1,100)))
```

Comment: how did you come up with the answer so quick? it's correct. thanks.

Comment: I do random stuff like this in excel all the time. With practice, anything becomes easier :) Also, I think I spotted the question just after you posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. (Its quite nice apart from the fudge at the end for the 0 case):

```
=(CEILING(A1/50,1)*50)-IF(MOD(FLOOR((A1-1)/50,1),2)=1,1,0)
```

In explanation:

1. (CEILING(A1/50,1)*50) rounds up to the next 50
2. IF(MOD(FLOOR(A1/50,1),2)=1,1,0) takes off 1 if the number is large than an odd multiple of 50

Comment: thx, but if A1=1300, then it should be 1299, however your formula doesn't.

Comment: Spotted and corrected, was put off by the typo in the question (1200 -> 1299)

Comment: if A1=1250, it should still be 1250, but your formula changes it to 1249.

Comment: Fixed again. I think I'm doing alright considering its 1am here in the UK! To be honest I prefer Tim's version (although the Maths is more interesting in mine)!